# How to reach the element itself inside jQuery’s `val`?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My code is the following:

```js
const pagedata = {
    name: "Value for name",
    email: "Value for email",
  };

$(".fillvalfromvar").val(pagedata[$(this).attr("id")]);
```

I need to fill all the elements having the `fillvalfromvar` class with the value of the variable pointed to by the element id. For example the HTML is the following:

```html
<input id="name" class="fillvalfromvar" type="text">
<input id="email" class="fillvalfromvar" type="text">
```

And I’d like to fill those `val`s with `pagedata["name"]` and `pagedata["email"]`, respectively.

But the `this` value isn’t pointing to the original element. What should I use instead?

Comment: How about to set `fillvalfromvar` into class property for each of your elements?

Comment: Why can't you just hardcode it in? What is `this` meant to refer to?

Comment: Some closely related variations: Mapping the current value (e.g. via a function, or appending something to it): [Modify the value of each textfield based on original value using jQuery](/q/24725927/4642212), and [Append text to input field](/q/841722/4642212); Using the index of the element in the collection: [Insert array values in inputs with specific class, index by index](/q/58516211/4642212).

Answer (score 4):

Use the syntax that [accepts a function as the parameter](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-functionindex--value)

```
$('.fillvalfromvar').val( function(){
   return pagedata[ this.id ];
});
```

(*assuming that those `input` elements have the `fillvalfromvar` class*)

---

or you could use the `.each()` method

```
$('.fillvalfromvar').each( function(){
   this.value = pagedata[ this.id ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use $.each

```
$('.fillvalfromvar').each(function(){
   $(this).val(pagedata[$(this).attr('id')]);
});
```

or use `$('input[id]')` if those inputs dont have the class mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.fillvalfromvar').each(function(){
     $(this).val(pagedata[$(this).attr('id')]);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to define the class of your input text:

```
<input id='name' type='text'  class="fillvalfromvar">
<input id='email' type='text' class="fillvalfromvar">
```

Please try this.

Comment: yeah, forget to post classes in HTML. But it was on a real code.

Comment: then you can try this as mentioned above by @gaby aka.
$('.fillvalfromvar').each( function(){
   this.value = pagedata[ this.id ];
});